# Rails - new_projects_path in routes but getting a 'No route matches' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm really new to rails and after watching several tutorials I decided to have a go at making a basic site. I'm at the start of development at the moment, but there's a snag, I can't seem to get `link_to` to work as I'm getting a `No route matches` error returned when I load the page.

This is my code for the index page

```
<h1>Projects#index</h1>
<%= link_to "Create new project", action: new_project_path %>
```

I'm getting `new_project_path` from my terminal when I enter the command `rake routes` here is everything that is returned:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action

        root GET    /                            projects#index
    projects GET    /projects(.:format)          projects#index
            POST    /projects(.:format)          projects#create
 new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
     project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
           PATCH    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
             PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
          DELETE    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
```

and here is the code from the `projects_controller` file:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def create
    @project = Project.create(project_params)
    if(@project.save)
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Project added"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end


  private 

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :desc, :dates)
  end

end
```

I'm just wondering where I'm going wrong because this has had e confused for a couple of hours now. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated! :)
I've checked the docs and can't seem to find my error so I really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
<%= link_to "Create new project", new_project_path %>
```

What you did here:

```
<%= link_to "Create new project", action: new_project_path %>
```

Says to make the `action` param equal to `"/projects/new"` which isn't what you're after all.

Comment: That's it! thank you :) sorry it was such an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any below methods:

```
<%= link_to "Create new project", new_project_path %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to "Create new project", controller: "projects", action: "new" %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to "Create new project", "/projects/new" %>
```